# Page layout using DIV column spanning multiple rows

Tags: html

I wish to generate a layout with two columns where the right column spans two rows. I want to do this only using DIV tags:

```
+-----------+-----------+
+           +           +
+           +           +
+-----------+           +
+           +           +
+           +           +
+-----------+-----------+
```

I have tried:

```
<div>
     <div style="float:left; width: 100px;"></div>
     <div style="float:right width: 100px;"></div>
     <div style="float:left; width: 100px;"></div>
</div>
```

But this didnt help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add an extra wrapper around the first column, so your markup looks like this:

```
<div>
     <div style="float:left; width: 100px;">
          <div>1a</div>
          <div>1b</div>
     </div>
     <div style="float:left; width: 100px;">2</div>
</div>
```

This should make the result look like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|     1a    |     2     |
|           |           |
+-----------+           |
|     1b    |           |
|           |           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use percentages to allow your layout to work depending on the size of the container.

```
<div id="container" style="height:100%;width: 100%;">
    <div style="float: left;width: 50%;height: 100%;">
        <div style="height: 50%;">
            First left
        </div>
        <div style="height: 50%;">
            Second left
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100%;">
        First right
    </div>
</div>
```